# How to optimize better mysql query?

Tags: mysql

I have written sql query:

```
select `b`.`id` as `id`, `b`.`name`, count(a.institution_id) as total 
from `premises` as `a` 
left join `institutions` as `b` on `b`.`id` = `a`.`institution_id` 
where exists (select id from rental_schedules as c where a.id = c.premises_id and public = 1 and public_enterprise = 0 and rental_schedule_status = 1 and date >= CURDATE()) 
group by `a`.`institution_id`
```

I have very large data in table (Over 1000000 rows) and this query takes up to 8-10 sec. Is there any possibility to optimize better this query?

Thanks for answers in advance!

Comment: Provide complete CREATE TABLE for all mentioned tables. Specify table aliases for all columns in the query.

Comment: *very large data in table (Over 1000000 rows)* What table of 3 mentioned ones? Provide statistic for all 3 tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The join to the `institutions` table can somewhat benefit from the following index:

```
CREATE INDEX inst_idx (id, name);
```

This index will cover the join and the select clause on this table.  The biggest improvement would come from the following index on the `rental_schedules` table:

```
CREATE INDEX rental_idx (premises_id, public, public_enterprise, rental_schedule_status, date);
```

This index would allow the exists clause to rapidly evaluate for each joined from the first two tables.

Also, I would rewrite your query to make it ANSI compliant, with the column in the `GROUP BY` clause matching the `SELECT` clause:

```sql
SELECT
    b.id AS id,
    b.name,    -- allowed, assuming that id be the primary key column of institutions
    COUNT(a.institution_id) AS total 
FROM premises AS a
LEFT JOIN institutions AS b ON b.id = a.institution_id
WEHRE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM rental_schedules AS c
              WHERE a.id = c.premises_id AND public = 1 AND
                    public_enterprise = 0 AND rental_schedule_status = 1 AND
                    date >= CURDATE()) 
GROUP BY
    b.id;
```

Comment: Wow, thanks, really appreaciate your help. Now query runs in miliseconds instead of seconds :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to deal the subquery as in memory as possible as you can. When the memory is lack of space, a temporary is created and a long time will be wasted.
As the [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/subquery-materialization.html) is described below:

> The optimizer uses materialization to enable more efficient subquery processing. Materialization speeds up query execution by generating a subquery result as a temporary table, normally in memory. The first time MySQL needs the subquery result, it materializes that result into a temporary table. Any subsequent time the result is needed, MySQL refers again to the temporary table. The optimizer may index the table with a hash index to make lookups fast and inexpensive. The index contains unique values to eliminate duplicates and make the table smaller.
>
> Subquery materialization uses an in-memory temporary table when possible, falling back to on-disk storage if the table becomes too large.